# Can I conjure a dagger or dart in my offhand and use bonus action to attack with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, summoning

I'm considering getting two levels as Conjuration Wizard to multiclass my Rogue, just because what I'm about to ask seems cool.

I want to use Minor Conjuration as an action to summon a dagger in my offhand, and use my bonus action with Two-weapon fighting to throw it as an attack.

Will this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No

The Two-weapon Fighting rules (Player's Handbook, page 195) are quite clear about the requirements for making the off-hand attack:

> **When you take the Attack action** and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

You cannot use Two-weapon Fighting without taking the Attack action. Other actions do not count.

Notably, since Two-weapon Fighting requires both weapons to also be light melee weapons, darts cannot be used - they are listed as ranged, not melee weapons.